# AudioKit and AUv3 Instrument

Tags: audiokit, auv3

I have currently an audio app, using AudioKit, that play samples with AKSampler and I'm now trying to make an AUv3 AudioUnit extension for my app.

I have successfully create my AUv3 extension (thanks to the AudioKit AUv3 tutorial) but now I can't figure how to connect my AudioKit AudioEngine to the AUv3 AudioUnit.

I have made a lot of searches about this, but I didn't find anything about AudioKit and Auv3 using audio (AudioKit AUv3 tutorial only talks about MIDI).

Does anyone here know how to connect AudioKit to an AUv3 AudioUnit extension ?

Thanks!!!

Comment: We're working on making this easier with AudioKit.  I'll post answer when its ready.